# Difference between PRF, Pseudorandom Function and Pseudorandom Function Family

Tags: pseudo-random-function, terminology

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family), PRF is an abbreviation for Pseudorandom function family. But [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3867/what-is-difference-between-prg-prf-and-prp/15203#15203) says that PRF means Pseudorandom Function. Does that mean that a Pseudorandom Function is the same as a Pseudorandom function family? Or is the abbreviation PRF used inconsistently?

Comment: Yes, they are family. Sometimes we say that a block cipher is a family of permutations and block-ciphers are synonyms with PRPs. Similarly, a PRF is a family of pseudo-random functions. In both a key select one permutation/ function from the set of permutations/functions. Well, this is a better answer in some sense [What is the difference between pseudorandom permutation/pseudorandom function/block cipher?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75305/18298)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "family" can mean various things. For instance, you have the SHA-2 family of hash functions. In this case the algorithms are part of a family because they are based on the same hash construction.

However, in this case the "family" simply means that you have a PRF construction, say HMAC-SHA256. In that case the "family" is actually the set of all the possible HMAC-SHA256 functions that can be selected using the key.

In other words, say that you have a family of keyed hash functions called $H$ and a key $k_0$ consisting of $\{0\}^{256}$, then $H_{k_0}$ is the function chosen by $k_0$ from the family.

Comment: Would $H$ and $H_{k_0}$ then both be called a PRF? Or only $H$?

Comment: I guess both, it depends on context. HMAC is a PRF construct(ion) and when keyed a function. To make it more complex, in API's you'd could HMAC a function as well as the key is then considered a parameter. Language is a fickle thing, but generally we know what is meant by "a PRF" and the distinction is clear or doesn't matter. For me the bigger problem is that "a PRF" can be too generic in the sense that a lot of constructions can be called a PRF or made into a PRF - for instance a KDF and a MAC construction both are (related) PRF's.

Answer (score 2):

PRF is short for PseudoRandom Function. A single function $F:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ cannot be pseudorandom. Pseudorandomness asks that it is not feasible to distinguish an oracle for $F$ from an oracle for a truly random function $f:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ (meaning that $f(x)$ is uniformly distributed for every $x\in\{0,1\}$). This is very easy to distinguish for a single $F$: send $x$ to an oracle and check if the output is equal to $F(x)$. Since $f(x)$ is uniform, $f(x)=F(x)$ only with probability $2^{-n}$.

So whenever we speak of pseudorandom functions, we actually mean function *families* $\{F_k\}_{k\in\{0,1\}^\lambda}$. In the pseudorandom distinguishing game, the distinguisher is given an oracle to $F_k$ for a random *unknown* $k$. Since $F_k$ is now one of exponentially many functions, the "attack" outlined above for a single function does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by '$f(x)$ is uniformly distributed' ? If $f(x)$ is a number, I would think that it is fixed, and thus not 'distributed'.

Comment: That would be short for all $y$  where $y = f(x)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are in $\{0, 1\}^n$ as made clear in the function definition.

Comment: The function $f$ is itself selected at random from the set of functions mapping $\{0,1\}^n$ to $\{0,1\}^n$, so if you look at one $x\in \{0,1\}^n$ then the maginal distribution of $f(x)$ is uniform over $\{0,1\}^n$.