# Can we use a PRF as a PRP?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation

Leaving aside the problem of how to compute the inverse of a PRF F, may we use it also as a PRP?

The reciprocal of this statement is true, see for instance Katz and Lindell, Proposition 3.27, when the input length of F is sufficiently large. However, in practice to build a PRP from a PRF people use a Feistel network. This would address the problem of making the PRF invertible.

Leaving aside the invertibility I guess the same proof for PRP $\implies$ PRF is useful here. Am I right?

Comment: See this [What is difference between PRG, PRF, and PRP](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3867/what-is-difference-between-prg-prf-and-prp/15203#15203)

Comment: @kelalaka I already read it. My quesion is not really adressed there

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question by mentioning Feistel networks?

Comment: @forest no, because they solve the problem of invertibility, but I say: "leaaving aside the problem of how to compute the inverse of a PRF"...

Comment: @Javier They don't solve the problem of invertibility, they just use a non-invertible PRF to construct an invertible PRP. From Wikipedia, "_One advantage of the Feistel model compared to a substitution–permutation network is that the round function $\operatorname{F}$ does not have to be invertible._"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the output domain is large enough so that the probability of getting a collision in the PRF is negligible, then the output of a PRP and PRF are indistinguishable. Thus, in principle, the answer is yes - you can interchange these freely (under the above condition).

Having said that, it's unclear to me why you would want a non-invertible PRP rather than a PRF. Typically, a PRF is better for cryptographic constructions, being easier to analyze and giving better bounds, and the only time we use a PRP is when we want to invert. Maybe there is an example of a use of a PRP specifically when inversion is not needed, but I don't think I've ever seen one (and can't really think of where it would be helpful).